# Extract numpy rows by given condition

Tags: python, numpy

I have numpy array as follows.

```
import numpy as np


data = np.array([[0,0,0,4],
                [3,0,5,0],
                 [8,9,5,3]])

print (data)
```

I have to extract only those lines which first three elements are not all zeros
expected result is as follows:

```
result = np.array([[3,0,5,0],
                 [8,9,5,3]])
```

I tried as:

```
res = [l for l in data if l[:3].sum() !=0]
print (res)
```

It gives result. But, looking for better, numpy way of doing it.

Comment: yes, looking for numpy way....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`sum` is a bit unreliable if your array can contain negative numbers, but `any` will always work:

```
result = data[data[:, :3].any(1)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You say

> first three elements are not all zeros

so a solution is

```py
import numpy as np

data = np.array([[0,0,0,4],
                 [3,0,5,0],
                 [8,9,5,3]])

data[~np.all(data[:, :3] == 0, axis=1), :]
```

Comment: "Not all" is "any" with more steps and temp arrays

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to explaing how I think about these kinds of problems through my answer.

First step: define a function that returns a boolean indicating whether this is a good row.
For that, I use np.any, which checks if any of the entries is "True" (for integers, true is non-zero).

```
import numpy as np
v1 = np.array([1, 1, 1, 0])
v2 = np.array([0, 0, 0, 1])
good_row = lambda v: np.any(v[:3])
good_row(v1)
Out[28]: True
good_row(v2)
Out[29]: False
```

Second step: I apply this on all rows, and obtain a masking vector. To do so, one can use the 'axis' keyword in 'np.any', which will apply this on columns or rows depending on the axis value.

```
np.any(data[:, :3], axis=1)
Out[32]: array([False,  True,  True])
```

Final step: I combine this with indexing, to wrap it all.

```
rows_inds = np.any(data[:, :3], axis=1)
data[rows_inds]
Out[37]: 
array([[3, 0, 5, 0],
       [8, 9, 5, 3]])
```